# RxJava observable completed but doOnComplete callback not triggered in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

I have following logic for creating an observable data from completable (with `doOnComplete` callback), which is unit tested:

```
class ObservableSrc(val completableSrc: CompletableSrc) {

    fun getObservable(client: Client): Observable<State> {
        return client.getResults()
            .concatMap { processResult(client, it.values) }
    }

    private fun processResult(Client: Client, values: Values): Observable<State> =
        completableSrc.getCompletable(client.type, values)
            .doOnComplete { client.doSomething(values)}
            .toSingleDefault(…)
            .map { … }
            .toObservable()
            .startWith(State.InProgress)
}

@Test
fun test() {
    whenever(client.type).doReturn(Type.SOME_TYPE)
    whenever(client.getResults()).doReturn(Observable.just<Result>(Result(mock())))
    whenever(completableSrc.getCompletable(any(), any())).doReturn(Completable.complete())
    doNothing().whenever(client).doSomething(any())

    val observer = tested.getObservable(client).test()

    observer.assertComplete()
    verify(completableSrc, times(1)).getCompletable(any(), any())
    verify(client, times(1)).doSomething(any())
}
```

The problem is that verifying `doSomething` gives that there were 2 interaction with mock `client` but desired method was not called. I found that if I change chaining a little bit like that:

```
completableSrc.getCompletable(client.type, values)
                .toSingleDefault(…)
                .map { … }
                .doOnSuccess { client.doSomething(values)}
                .toObservable()
                .startWith(State.InProgress)
```

then it works. I just don't know why the previous version with `doOnComplete` is failing (`observer.assertComplete()` is executed successfully).  It seems like it's disposed too soon so the callback is not called but why?

Comment: Is completable supposed to hit completion stage on any of those chained method calls?

Comment: Where does `startWith` come from? From what I can see, you are converting the `Completable` to `Single` (`.toSingleDefault(…)`) but `Single` doesn't have `startWith` (because it does make sense since it only emits one value)

Comment: My bad, `startWith` comes from observable after calling `toObservable`. I updated the question. The completable is a network call (Retrofit with Rx), but it's mocked in unit test.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

Testing the code using Unit Test and Mocks. I use **kolin.test** and **mockk** for personal preferences.

```
interface CompletableSrc {
    fun getCompletable(): Completable
}

interface Client {
    fun doSomething()
    fun doSomethingElse()
}

class CompletableTest {

    @Test
    fun `functions doOnComplete and doOnSuccess should work as expected`() {
        val completableSrc: CompletableSrc = mockk {
            every { getCompletable() } returns Completable.complete()
        }

        val client: Client = mockk {
            every { doSomething() } returns Unit
            every { doSomethingElse() } returns Unit
        }

        val observable = completableSrc.getCompletable()
            .doOnComplete { client.doSomething() }
            .toSingleDefault(0)
            .map { it + 1 }
            .doOnSuccess { client.doSomethingElse() }
            .toObservable()
            .startWith(-1)

        val test = observable.test()
        test.assertComplete()
        test.assertValues(-1, 1)

        verify(exactly = 1) {
            completableSrc.getCompletable()
            client.doSomething()
            client.doSomethingElse()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both the assertions and the mock verifications succeeded.

**Previous**

Your code should be working fine, for me is really hard to tell what's wrong because I can't run it, but I create a snippet which is doing pretty much the same thing and it works as expected.

**Example**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var sideEffect = 0

    val observable = Completable.complete()
        .doOnComplete { sideEffect += 1 }
        .toSingleDefault(sideEffect)
        .map { sideEffect + 1 }
        .doOnSuccess(::println)
        .toObservable()
        .startWith(-1)

    val test = observable.test()
    test.assertComplete()
    test.assertValues(-1, 2)
}
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Both side-effect functions `Completable.doOnComplete` and `Single.doOnSuccess` are executed, updating the variable `sideEffect` and printing to the console.

Comment: You're right, the code is running fine in the app. Did you try to run it with JUnit?

Comment: So in your example `assertComplete` and `verify` are successful. In mine there is only `assertComplete`.  Can you mock `doSomething` to do nothing on interaction and see the result? I'll try to look around my mocks - maybe there is something wrong with them.

Comment: @Luke Actually it's mocked (`every { doSomething() } returns Unit`), if not it would have thrown an Exception

Comment: I know. I mean to use exactly "do nothing" mock (just like in my code). I'm trying to reflect my code in yours but I'm almost out of ideas.